# How to bind XDocument to TreeView with different data templates for different element levels?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview, linq-to-xml

I have this simple XML:

```
<ChangeLog>
    <Release Version="1.0.1">
        <Change Name="Feature2" Description="Something changed"/>
        <Change Name="Feature1" Description="Bug fixed"/>
    </Release>
    <Release Version="1.0.0">
        <Change Name="Feature2" Description="Something new added"/>
        <Change Name="Feature1" Description="Something new added"/>
    </Release>
</ChangeLog>
```

I want to display it in a `TreeView` like this:

[image]

I've been looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669141.aspx) and some other related links, but examples I found uses single `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to display items, while I need `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for `Release` elements, and `DataTemplate` for `Change` elements.

For example, in case of view models, there will be something like this in resources (the template trees are omitted):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Release}" ItemsSource="{Binding Changes}" />
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Change}" ItemsSource="{Binding Changes}" />
```

Is it ever possible without wrapping XML into view models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out, how to do this.

The root of the solution is `DataTemplateSelector` to provide appropriate data template for different XML elements:

```
public sealed class ElementsTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ReleaseTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ChangeTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = item as XElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            switch (element.Name.ToString())
            {
                case "Release":
                    return ReleaseTemplate;
                case "Change":
                    return ChangeTemplate;
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Then XAML will look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ElementsTemplateSelector x:Key="ElementsTemplateSelectorKey">
            <local:ElementsTemplateSelector.ReleaseTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Release:"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Attribute[Version].Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </local:ElementsTemplateSelector.ReleaseTemplate>

            <local:ElementsTemplateSelector.ChangeTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=":"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Attribute[Description].Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ElementsTemplateSelector.ChangeTemplate>
        </local:ElementsTemplateSelector>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Elements}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ElementsTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
</Grid>
```

P.S. This code assumes, that current data context is `XDocument` instance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = XDocument.Load("file://D:/ChangeLog.xml");
    }
}
```